# SharpDX + ColorMatrix

Tags: c#, directx

Ковыряюсь в `SharpDX`. Хочу добавить эффект `ColorMatrix`. Пишу нижеприведенный код, но на строчке `colorEffect.Matrix = Matrix5x4.Identity;` программа падает с эксепшеном "The parameter is incorrect". С чем это связано? Матрицы не работают никакие, даже единичная, как в моем примере.

```
private SharpDX.Direct2D1.Effect CreateEffectGraph(SharpDX.WIC.FormatConverter formatConverter, Vector2 scale, float blurDeviation)
        {
            var d2dDevice = _deviceManager.DeviceDirect2D;
            var d2dContext = _deviceManager.ContextDirect2D;

            SharpDX.Direct2D1.Effects.BitmapSourceEffect bitmapSourceEffect = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Effects.BitmapSourceEffect(d2dContext);

            bitmapSourceEffect.ScaleSource = scale;
            bitmapSourceEffect.Orientation = Orients[this.Rotation];            
            bitmapSourceEffect.WicBitmapSource = formatConverter;

            SharpDX.Direct2D1.Effects.ColorMatrix colorEffect = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Effects.ColorMatrix(d2dContext);
            colorEffect.SetInput(0, bitmapSourceEffect.Output, true);

            colorEffect.Matrix = Matrix5x4.Identity;

            return colorEffect;

        }
```

Comment: попробуй иниц. матрицу через конструктор. т.е. new Matrix5x4().

Comment: пробовал. тоже самое